# python fabric get public ip address

Tags: python, fabric

Try to get public ip address of host with python fabric

```
def publicip():
        ip = local("curl -s 'http://checkip.dyndns.org' | sed 's/.*Current IP Address: \([0-9\.]*\).*/\'\1/g\'")
        print (red(ip))
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 2) while executing 'curl -s 'http://checkip.dyndns.org' | sed 's/.*Current IP Address: \([0-9\.]*\).*/'/g''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `local()` doesn't support multiple commands to be executed. You can however split the execution into:

```
def publicip():
    ip = local("curl -s 'http://checkip.dyndns.org'", capture=True)
```

and then ip will contain the desired html:

```
'<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 1.2.3.4</body></html>'
```

Which you can parse using regex, e.g.:

```
r = re.compile(r'.*\<body>Current IP Address:\s(.*)\</body>.*')
final_ip = r.match(ip).group(1)
```

Comment: It's better to use stdlib for this than shell out to curl.

Comment: @Morgan: agree, it was just an example how to make the code in the question to work.

Answer (score 3):

Curl is probably not installed on the host you're running on. You don't need it anyway as you can do this easily in Python like this:

```
import urllib2

u = urllib2.urlopen('http://checkip.dyndns.org')
line = u.next()
print line.split("<")[6].split().pop()
```

Comment: Hmm ... Jon's regex is better at finding IP address. You might still want to use urllib2 if you don't have requests installed on your host.  But if you do requests is far better library :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `local()` (executes an external command?) is, but using the `requests` library and `re.search` this is fairly simple:

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('http://checkip.dyndns.org')
myip = re.search(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', r.text).group()
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure python implementation is

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://ipof.in/txt')
myip = r.text
```

Thats it.  Do check out http://ipof.in if you need further information beyond just IP address